# Problems consuming php soap service with jaxws where multi-reference objects are included

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws

I try to consume a php web service which returns in its response multi-reference objects. I created the java client with wsimport and can call the soap methods without any problems. But in the response the objects which should be filled accordingly the objects are empty:

basic part of the output in the soap envelope:

```
<result>
 <book id="extref1">
  <title>Refactoring</title>
 </book>
 <book id="extref2">
  <title>Clean Code</title>
 </book>
 <library name="lib1">
  <book href="#extref1"/>
  <book href="#extref2"/>
 <library>
 <library name="lib2">
  <book href="#extref2"/>
 <library>
</result>
```

Debugging in Java the result.getBook()-List is filled with the right objects, but library[0].getBook()-List is only filled with the right amount of book-Objects but these objects are empty (e.g. title is null).

SoapClients in php are unmarshalling the response correctly, but I need to consume it in Java as well.

Comment: What does library[0].getBook().get(0).getHref() return? Is it null? If not, I guess you have to auto-wire these objects in Java client manually, as I haven't faced that auto-wiring of that kind of messages yet. (Maybe only your php ws client does this for you)

Comment: As this attribute is injected by the marshalling process in php and not defined explicitly in the wsdl there is no href member in Book class.

Comment: If its not in WSDL, then don't expect to be handled by Java client. Maybe there are options in PHP for generating WSDLs for other clients, different than PHP?

Comment: I am just looking into php soap stack source code. this problems is not related to wsdl (the wsdls are not generated by php in this case). As far as I understand this, soap standard is defining that the implementing server may do this kind of node referencing by just utilizing the id and href attributes despite they are not declared in the wsdl.